# HLS Nginx and Streaming Media

Tags: nginx, streaming, http-live-streaming

This is a process question more then anything.

I've been reading up on HTTP streaming (HLS) over the past week.

My goal is to be able to deliver content from my NGINX web server using HLS.

I have looked at Clappr using HLS.js. as a player however I'm just unclear what I need to do to deliver the content. Do I need a streaming media sever? just a web server?

I think I can use ffmpeg to make the HLS streams.

Eventually I'm hoping to be able to record incoming streams for processing later. Right now I just want to be able to put out HLS streams.

Any advice or infographic or something to put this in perspective would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I need a streaming media sever? just a web server?

One of the main purposes of HLS is that you can serve the data with any HTTP server.  Content is effectively files done in chunks.  No special streaming server is needed.  Nginx is fine.